# I am it confused about the changing of order of triple integral in cylindrical coordinate system. Can someone help me with detailed explanation?

Tags: integration

I am a bit confused by this question. Can someone help me with a detailed explanation? I am stuck and can't understand how to strat 
Change the order and then evaluate
$$
\int_{3}^{4} \int_{2\pi}^{4\pi} \int_{0}^{\theta}{rzdzd\theta dr}
$$
No particular order is mentioned. So, I have tried to change the order into
$$
d\theta dzdr
$$
The limit of
$$
{\theta}
$$ I have calculated as
$$
z
$$ to $${4\pi}$$.
The limit of r is the same. But what is the limit of
$$
\theta
$$
. Also, are the limits for r and z correct?

Comment: What did you try? You should edit the question to provide more context and show your attempt / thoughts.

Comment: Also change the order of integration to which order?

Comment: Ok. I am editing the question.

Comment: But your edit does not mention anything about your thoughts on the question. You decide the order and tell us how you would go about changing the limits and where you are getting stuck. Otherwise this question will get closed pretty quickly.

Comment: I have edited as you advised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to visualize, the region is between two cylinders of radius $3$ and $4$ with base at $z = 0$ and the height changes as we move radially in proportion to the value of $\theta$. Think of its top bound by a spiral.

The limits of $\theta$ is correct for $2 \pi \leq z \leq 4 \pi$ but for $0 \leq z \leq 2\pi$, bounds of $\theta$ is independent of $z$ as the minimum height is $z = 2 \pi$ and $\theta = 2\pi$.

Also $r$ can be anywhere in the order of integration. It does not make a difference. So please split it into two integrals for the order $d\theta ~ dz ~ dr$.

i) For $0 \leq z \leq 2 \pi, 2 \pi \leq \theta \leq 4 \pi$

ii) For $2 \pi \leq z \leq 4 \pi, z \leq \theta \leq 4 \pi$

and finally $3 \leq r \leq 4$