# Is the change of order of the integration correct?

Tags: multiple-integral

The question is
Change the order and then evaluate
$$
\int_{3}^{4} \int_{2\pi}^{4\pi} \int_{0}^{\theta}{rzdzd\theta dr}
$$
I am trying to change the order into
$$
drd{\theta}dz
$$
Here, I have confusion. What I have done, I am mentioning below.
$$
\int_{0}^{4\pi}\int_{z}^{4\pi}\int_{3}^{4}{rzdrd{\theta}dz}
$$
Is it Correct?

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked yesterday and I answered? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4260072/i-am-it-confused-about-the-changing-of-order-of-triple-integral-in-cylindrical-c

Comment: Yes. But the order here is drd{theta}dz. So, will it be the same as you have said? Your answer was helpful though.

Comment: order of $dr$ does not matter. You can write it as -   $ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{2\pi}^{4\pi}\int_{3}^{4} r z ~ dr ~ d\theta ~ dz ~ + ~ $ $ \displaystyle \int_{2\pi}^{4\pi}\int_{z}^{4\pi}\int_{3}^{4} r z ~ dr ~ d\theta ~ dz$

Comment: or you can express it as $ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{4\pi}\int_{max(2\pi, z)}^{4\pi}\int_{3}^{4} r z ~ dr ~ d\theta ~ dz$ which finally comes down to the above split integral.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for this clarification.